# Graphviz Selfloops overlap labels

Tags: layout, graphviz, dot

I have a simple graphiz graph that I am trying to render with dot.  It is a series of self-loops on a single state:

```
digraph FST {
size = "8.5,11";
label = "";
rankdir=LR;
bgcolor = "transparent";
center = 1;
rank = same;
margin = 0;
orientation = Portrait;
0 [label = "0", shape = doublecircle, style = bold, fontsize = 14, color="#339933"]
    0 -> 0 [label = "a", fontsize = 14];
    0 -> 0 [label = "b", fontsize = 14];
    0 -> 0 [label = "cd", fontsize = 14];
    0 -> 0 [label = "efg", fontsize = 14];
    0 -> 0 [label = "a", fontsize = 14];
    0 -> 0 [label = "q", fontsize = 14];
    0 -> 0 [label = "xyzabc", fontsize = 14];
}
```

I compile this like:

```
 $ cat self-loop.dot | dot -Tpng > self-loop.png
```

The edges however, overlap the labels and looks ridiculous.  Is there some way to prevent the edges from doing this? To make them flare out more?

[Resulting Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNv0R.png)

I have had no luck scouring forums or the graphviz documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-loops are a pain.  Using ports (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos) helps.  Bur rankdir also causes problems, so I changed it.

```
digraph FST {
size = "8.5,11";
label = "";
//rankdir=LR;  // note the change in rankdir!!
bgcolor = "transparent";
center = 1;
rank = same;
margin = 0;
orientation = Portrait;
0 [label = "0", shape = doublecircle, style = bold, fontsize = 14, color="#339933"]
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "a", fontsize = 14];
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "\nb", fontsize = 14];
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "\ncd", fontsize = 14];
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "\nefg  ", fontsize = 14];
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "  a  ", fontsize = 14];
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "  q  ", fontsize = 14];
    0:nw -> 0:ne [label = "xyzabc", fontsize = 14];
}
```

Giving:
[image]